# Sequence contains no match element but Element is there

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I have a simple search box and button that is bound to a command, the command fires fine and passes the textbox parameter but when it hits the SearchStock method it runs through the list and doesn't match the parameter even though the element is there? Don't understand why its not matching, possibly my poor LINQ skills

Search Stock method

```
private void SearchStock(object _ticker)
    {
         var stock = Stocks.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Ticker == _ticker.ToString());
        _selectedstock = (Stock)stock;           
        
    }
```

When I step into it it is showing the element ticker, I noticed that there were spaces after the Ticker name so I changed the column to NVARCHAR but it still didn't work

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please place a breakpoint on the `}`, then show me a screenshot indicating a) that the element is there (use the locals window to show the value of the matching Stock.Ticker), b) what the result of `_ticker.ToString()` is (use the Immediate window) and c) that stock is null (locals window again)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At the moment we don't know what `Stocks` is, or what `_ticker` is. (We don't even know if this is LINQ to Objects, EF Core, something else...) Without more information, we're very unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: Is your search box is TextBox and are you sending parameter as string or just component? If you are sending component directly, you have to cast _ticker to textbox and use that. ((TextBox)_ticker).Text

Comment: @Ramazan I'm sending it just as a string,is that not the same as _ticker.ToString() ????

Comment: @F.OLeary are you comparing them with data and it is exactly same? Like, uppercase, lowercase characters and spaces. In first picture, you have "FB" and in second picture you have "FB " (with extra space). Could be you are adding space somewhere?

Comment: Just comparing uppercase strings, Ya thats what I noticed aswell but can't understand where the extra space is added, I changed the column type to NVARCHAR in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you find why it is not working all alone. "FB " is not equal to "FB".
You have 2 options :

- Try to fix the used stored database string format.
- use `var stock = Stocks.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Ticker.Trim() == _ticker.ToString());` to ignore space in code

Comment: I just changed the datatype to NVARCHAR(4) which solves the problem for the 4 character Tickers but it's still adding the spaces to the shorter tickers which is strange

Comment: I think as the previous type was "VARCHAR" it created the spaces at the end. When you change the type to "NVARCHAR(3)" it don't modify the data inside so the space is kept.

Comment: Try to trim you data inside you database after a type change like this.

Comment: Ah Ok, it's not changing the data that is already stored, it's working now though, Thank's for the assistance Sir @Orkad